# Best way to mark seams and unwrap this mesh?

Tags: uv

I want to unwrap and texture paint this mesh,but as you can see it looks like a mess in the uv editor right now. Where can i add seams? what is the best place ? when i tried it as it is (with smart uv unwrap), it just stretches my texture and looks awful.

[image]

Comment: weird because Smart UV Project should work fine, could you share your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apply scale** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to your model before unwrapping it with Smart UV Project to prevent the texture from stretching.